# error in view python django

Tags: python, django, unicode, view

```
def projectDetail(request):
    data = {'error':''}
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    if len(projects) == 0:
        data['error']='NO Project Information Available'
        html ="<html><body>%s</body></html>"%data['error']
        return HttpResponse(html)
    project = projects[0]
    html ="<html><body><ul>Project Description \
              <li>Project Name:"+project.name+"</li>\
              <li>Project Phase:"+ project.phase+"</li>\
              <li>Project City: "+ project.city+"</li>\
              <li>Project Description:"+project.description+"</li>\
              <li>Builder Name:"+ project.builders.all()[0].name+"</li>\
              <li>Builder Description:"+ project.builders.all()[0].description+"</li>\
              <li>Builder Type:"+ project.builders.all()[0].builder_type.name+"</li>\
              </ul></body></html>"
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

this is my code and when I requests this view I get error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, City found
```

what is the solution of this

Answer (score 3):

That error will be coming from this line:

```
<li>Project City: "+ project.city+"</li>\
```

You presumably need to add a [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods) or [`__unicode__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode) method on your City model.

That said - you really shouldn't be building up HTML responses like that - use [Django's template engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) instead. [Part 3 of the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/) might help you get started here.

Answer (score 1):

```
 projects = Project.objects.all()
```

It is an iterator object and for you need to iterate over it got get project details.
     for project in projects:
         project.city
         project.your field

if city is different table or a relationship key, you need to define

```
 def __str__(self):     # for django 2.* version    
     return self.name
```

and

```
def __unicode__(self):
     return self.name       # for django 3.* version
```